# Webpack to load uri type "url:./myfile.ttf"

Tags: webpack, fonts, parcel

I have many projects using parcel2, I recently started to theme all these projects and I showcase that work using styleguidist which unfortunately uses webpack.

When adding fonts, I worked exclusively with styleguidist for a while (silly me) and it works well, but when moving to parcel2 I encountered issues. The solution is easy for parcel, but makes the code incompatible between webpack and parcel.

Here is what I used to have and what works with webpack:

```
import quicksand from "../fonts/Quicksand-VariableFont_wght.ttf";
```

This is using a file-loader configured as follows:

```
                {
                    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        esModule: false,
                        name: "[name].[ext]",
                    },
                },
```

To make this work with parcel2 I have to turn it into:

```
import quicksand from "url:../fonts/Quicksand-VariableFont_wght.ttf";
```

Notice the "url:" added at the start. And this works perfectly for parcel but now webpack is being annoying.

As I see it I have 2 options:

- tweak webpack to accept "url:" and link it to file-loader somehow
- tweak parcel so it links ttf files with "url:" automagically

I've tried a fair bit, preparsing, transorming, aliasing and could not get it to work both in parcel and webpack.

I'm mainly focusing on tweaking the webpack side of things as there's quite a few parcel projects and only one webpack one but if there's an easy solution with parcel, I'll get through the grind of updating all projects :)

Any help will be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has an idea on how to do this with webpack I'm still interested. In the meantime I found a solution using .parcelrc

```
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "transformers": {
        "*.ttf": [
            "@parcel/transformer-raw",
        ],
    },
}
```

This will automatically load ttf files using the transformer-raw which is used when you add "url:"